# On withdraw the value doesn't reset

Tags: solidity, dapps, react

I have a lottery contract that works fine except with the withdraw part.

Every time i call the function all goes well, transaction goes ok and token is transfered but on the frontend it never gets reset.

For example, i have 5000 tokens to withdraw, i do it, all goes ok and it keeps saying i still have 5000 tokens to withdraw even after i already have done that.

Once the draw winner function is called, all the values are calculated and the lottery resets. Then if your the owner of the contract you have the option to withdraw some taxes. And it's on that part that i have a problem. Every time i try to collect the taxes, it collects but never resets the value. It maintains the same value.

This is the function:

```
//withdraw project fees
function WithdrawProject(
    address _tokenAddress,
    address _project_wallet,
    uint256 _operatorTotalProject
) isOperator external returns (bool) {
    IERC20 _token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    address _project = _project_wallet;
    uint256 project2Transfer = _operatorTotalProject;
    _operatorTotalProject = 0;
    _token.transferFrom(lotteryOperator, _project, project2Transfer);
    return true;
}
```

And on the frontend:

```
const onWithdrawProject = async () => {
    const notification = toast.loading("Withdrawing project fees...");
    tokenPayment([project, BigInt(totalProject * (10 ** undoDecimal / 100))], {    
      onSuccess: async () => {
      try {
        const data = await withdrawProject([
          Token,
          project,
          totalProject,
          {gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('10', 'gwei')}
        ],
        );
        toast.success('Your withdrawn went successfully!', {
          id: notification
        });
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error('Whoops! something went wrong!', {
          id: notification
        })
        console.log(" ~ withdrawProject ~ error", error);
      }
    }
  })
};
```

I can't figured out how to reset the values once the withdraw is complete. Any help would be great, thanks

Full contract here:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

/// @notice Thrown when transfer of tokens at ERC20 `tokenAddress` fails
error DEX__TokenTransferFailed(address tokenAddress);

contract Lottery {
// Libraries
using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
using Address for address;

uint256 public constant ticketPrice = 100000000000000; //equals 10000 per ticket
uint256 public undoDecimal = 10;
uint256 public constant maxTickets = 100; // maximum tickets per lottery
uint256 public constant maxTicketsAllow = 5; // maximum tickets each player can get in the lottery
uint256 public constant comProject = 15; // commission for project
uint256 public constant duration = 1440 minutes; // The duration set for the lottery
address public project_wallet = 0x123;
uint256 public expiration; // Timeout in case That the lottery was not carried out.
address public lotteryOperator; // the crator of the lottery
uint256 public operatorTotalProject = 0; // the total commission balance
address public lastWinner; // the last winner of the lottery
uint256 public lastWinnerAmount; // the last winner amount of the lottery
uint256 public lotteryId; // get lotteryID

mapping(address => uint256) public winnings; // maps the winners to there winnings
address[] public tickets; //array of purchased Tickets

event Received(address, uint256);

receive() external payable {
    emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

// modifier to check if caller is the lottery operator
modifier isOperator() {
    require(
        (msg.sender == lotteryOperator),
        "Caller is not the lottery operator"
    );
    _;
}
// modifier to check if caller is a winner
modifier isWinner() {
    require(IsWinner(), "Caller is not a winner");
    _;
}
// modifier to check if caller is the lottery operator
modifier isOwnable() {
    require(
        (msg.sender == lotteryOperator),
        "Only owner can change ownership"
    );
    _;
}
constructor() {
    lotteryOperator = msg.sender;
    expiration = block.timestamp + duration;
    lotteryId = 1;
}
//transfer ownership of the contract
function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public {
    require(msg.sender == lotteryOperator);
    lotteryOperator = _newOwner;  
}
// return all the tickets
function getTickets() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    return tickets;
}
//get user balance
function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
    IERC20 _token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    return _token.balanceOf(msg.sender);
}
//get winnings for user address
function getWinningsForAddress(address addr) public view returns (uint256) {
    return winnings[addr];
}
//get lottery ID
function getLotteryId() public view returns(uint256) {
    return lotteryId;
}
//buytickets for lunaT
function BuyTickets(
    address _tokenAddress,
    uint256 _numOfTicketsToBuy
) public {
    require(
        _numOfTicketsToBuy <= RemainingTickets(),
        "Not enough tickets available."
    );
    IERC20 _token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    uint256 _tokenDecimal = IERC20Metadata(_tokenAddress).decimals();
    uint256 _totalCost = _numOfTicketsToBuy * (ticketPrice * (10 ** (_tokenDecimal - undoDecimal)));
    require(getBalance(_tokenAddress) >= _totalCost, "Not enough balance");

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _numOfTicketsToBuy; i++) {
        tickets.push(msg.sender);
    }
    if (!_token.transferFrom(msg.sender, lotteryOperator, _totalCost))
        revert DEX__TokenTransferFailed(address(_token));
}
//let's draw a winner
function DrawWinnerTicket() public isOperator {
    require(tickets.length > 0, "No tickets were purchased");

    bytes32 blockHash = blockhash(block.number - tickets.length);
    uint256 randomNumber = uint256(
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, blockHash))
    );
    uint256 winningTicket = randomNumber % tickets.length;
    address winner = tickets[winningTicket];
    lastWinner = winner;
    winnings[winner] += (tickets.length * ticketPrice) / 2;
    lastWinnerAmount = winnings[winner];
    operatorTotalProject += (tickets.length * ticketPrice) * comProject / 100;
    delete tickets;
    expiration = block.timestamp + duration;
    lotteryId++;
}
//let's restart the draw
function restartDraw() public isOperator {
    require(tickets.length == 0, "Cannot Restart Draw as Draw is in play");
    delete tickets;
    expiration = block.timestamp + duration;
}
//let's check winner amount
function checkWinningsAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
    address winner = msg.sender;
    uint256 reward2Transfer = winnings[winner];
    return reward2Transfer;
}

//withdraw winner winnings
function WithdrawWinnings(
    address _tokenAddress,
    address _lastWinner
) public isWinner {
    IERC20 _token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    address _winner = _lastWinner;
    uint256 reward2Transfer = lastWinnerAmount;
    lastWinnerAmount = 0;
    _token.transferFrom(lotteryOperator, _winner, reward2Transfer);
}
//withdraw project fees
function WithdrawProject(
    address _tokenAddress,
    address _project_wallet
) public isOperator {
    IERC20 _token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    address _project = _project_wallet;
    uint256 project2Transfer = operatorTotalProject;
    operatorTotalProject = 0;
    _token.transferFrom(lotteryOperator, _project, project2Transfer);
}
//Is a winner?
function IsWinner() public view returns (bool) {
    return winnings[msg.sender] > 0;
}
//current winning reward
function CurrentWinningReward() public view returns (uint256) {
    return tickets.length * ticketPrice;
}
//tickets left in the lottery
function RemainingTickets() public view returns (uint256) {
    return maxTickets - tickets.length;
}
//set expiration time
function setExpireTime(uint256 _time) public isOperator {
    expiration = _time;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add more details of the contract, like storage variables etc?

Comment: Basically what i need is to make that onSuccess async resets the value of the pool.

Comment: It seems that your problem is on the contract side, at least from the code you share... so it would be helpful if you share a bit more so I can reply to your question.

Comment: All contract is above.

Comment: So the WithdrawProject() function is much different from the one you previously shared. In the first you were changing a parameter, which would have the result you were describing. This last one doesn't have that problem, although has others... Have you thought about people sending different token addresses to your functions? Just an idea...
Does the problem persist with this last contract code?

Comment: Yeah, still the same issue... Values aren't reset once the functions are executed.